# Can't get HTML select form to display selected home_state that the user saved to a database previously

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When an user select any state and save it then on reload, it only returns first state which is Alabama. I checked the database via rails console to confirm that it saved correctly and it did but the HTML select isn't just getting the correct field.  Other fields are receiving correct values.

Here's _contact_info.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <%= f.select :home_state, options_for_select(us_states), id: "home_state",
  prompt: "State", class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

Application_controller.rb

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <%= f.select :home_state, options_for_select(us_states), id: "home_state",
      prompt: "State", class: "form-control" %>
    </div
```

us_states.helper

module UsStatesHelper

```
    def us_states
        [
          ['Alabama', 'AL'],
          ['Alaska', 'AK'],
          ['Arizona', 'AZ'],
          ['Arkansas', 'AR'],
          ['California', 'CA'],
          ['Colorado', 'CO'],
          ['Connecticut', 'CT'],
          ['Delaware', 'DE'],
          ['District of Columbia', 'DC'],
          ['Florida', 'FL'],
          ['Georgia', 'GA'],
          ['Hawaii', 'HI'],
          ['Idaho', 'ID'],
          ['Illinois', 'IL'],
          ['Indiana', 'IN'],
          ['Iowa', 'IA'],
          ['Kansas', 'KS'],
          ['Kentucky', 'KY'],
          ['Louisiana', 'LA'],
          ['Maine', 'ME'],
          ['Maryland', 'MD'],
          ['Massachusetts', 'MA'],
          ['Michigan', 'MI'],
          ['Minnesota', 'MN'],
          ['Mississippi', 'MS'],
          ['Missouri', 'MO'],
          ['Montana', 'MT'],
          ['Nebraska', 'NE'],
          ['Nevada', 'NV'],
          ['New Hampshire', 'NH'],
          ['New Jersey', 'NJ'],
          ['New Mexico', 'NM'],
          ['New York', 'NY'],
          ['North Carolina', 'NC'],
          ['North Dakota', 'ND'],
          ['Ohio', 'OH'],
          ['Oklahoma', 'OK'],
          ['Oregon', 'OR'],
          ['Pennsylvania', 'PA'],
          ['Puerto Rico', 'PR'],
          ['Rhode Island', 'RI'],
          ['South Carolina', 'SC'],
          ['South Dakota', 'SD'],
      ['Tennessee', 'TN'],
      ['Texas', 'TX'],
      ['Utah', 'UT'],
      ['Vermont', 'VT'],
      ['Virginia', 'VA'],
      ['Washington', 'WA'],
      ['West Virginia', 'WV'],
      ['Wisconsin', 'WI'],
      ['Wyoming', 'WY']
    ]   end
```

end

Comment: `Application_controller.rb ` does not reflect your controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the value of the element you want to start selected. Something like

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
 <%= f.select :home_state, options_for_select(us_states, selected_state.abbreviation), id: "home_state",
  prompt: "State", class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags for more details